# In Intro.js and Intro.js-react, the first and second steps are positioned not properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, intro.js

The issue is like this.

When reloaded, the first step and pop-up show in the upper left corner instead of the center, this is the first problem for me. I expected it to position center as the Intro.js official document says.

[image]

Next, when you press "Next," the pop-up bites into the upper left corner and we can't see it. This is the second problem.

[image]

Furthermore, when "Next" is pressed, the pop-up also bites into the upper left corner and we can't see it. This is the second problem as well.

[image]

But furthermore, when "Next" is pressed, the pop-up appears in its normal expected position.

[image]

When you press "Next" again, the pop-up will still appear in the normal expected position.

[image]

The code looks like this.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { useState } from 'react';

// Intro.js, see the details here: https://introjs.com/
// Intro.js-react, see the details here: https://github.com/HiDeoo/intro.js-react
// @ts-ignore
const Steps = dynamic(() => import('intro.js-react').then((mod) => mod.Steps), {
  ssr: false
});

const Onboarding = () => {
  const [stepEnabled, setStepEnabled] = useState(true);
  const steps = [
    {
      title: 'Welcome!!',
      intro:
        'This is your dashboard. Once you have set up, numbers will be displayed.'
    },
    {
      element: '#user-settings',
      title: 'User Settings page',
      intro: 'You can jump to the User Settings page from here.',
      position: 'right'
    },
    {
      element: '#profile-list',
      intro: 'This is your profile list.',
      position: 'right'
    },
    {
      element: '#card-list',
      intro: 'This is your card list.',
      position: 'left'
    }
  ];
  const onExit = () => {
    setStepEnabled(true);
  };
  const options = {
    showProgress: true,
    showBullets: true,
    exitOnOverlayClick: true,
    exitOnEsc: true,
    nextLabel: 'Next',
    prevLabel: 'Prev',
    // skipLabel: 'Skip',
    hidePrev: true,
    doneLabel: 'Done',
    overlayOpacity: 0.5,
    overlayColor: '#000',
    showStepNumbers: true,
    keyboardNavigation: true,
    scrollToElement: true,
    helperElementPadding: 10,
    showButtons: true
  };

  // if (!stepEnabled) {
  //   return null;
  // }
  return (
    <Steps
      // @ts-ignore
      enabled={stepEnabled}
      steps={steps}
      initialStep={0}
      onExit={onExit}
      options={options}
    />
  );
};

export default Onboarding;
```

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can give customized css class to every object in intro.js like this :

```
{
  element: ".test",
  intro: "",
  tooltipClass: "tooltipCustomClass",
  tooltipPosition: "bottom-center",
},
```

In global.scss file:

```
  .tooltipCustomClass{
      background-color: transparent;
      font-size: 12px ;
      color: white;
}
```

Here is the documentation to customize:
https://introjs.com/docs/examples/customizing/css-class

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I would like to ask, where does the `tooltipPosition: "bottom-center"` come from? Is it available by default? I tried it and it doesn't give me any errors, but it doesn't change the position.

Comment: You're welcome . Yes it is default values of into.js. its values are "bottom-center" "top-center" like this left right and ...

Comment: Thank you. I just...can't get it to work. I tried adding it to the first step, but nothing special happens.

Comment: You can write a css class for example give it margin auto or flex and justify center then give this class to tooltipclass for making it center

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).